# Button to show choose a file to upload dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-5

Instead of using an `input type="file"` html tag,  is it possible to bring up a `choose a file to upload` dialog box by clicking a `input type="button"`?  Then when a file is selected from the `choose a file to upload` dialog box, the file path gets inserted into a regular html `input type="text"` tag?

I've seem that gmail does something similar but not with buttons and text inputs, they simply have a link `add file` or something like that.  When that link is clicked, it shows the `select file(s) to upload by mail.google.com` dialog box.  When a file is clicked, the file name is shown on the screen.

How are they doing that?

Comment: If you right click on "Attach a file" in Gmail you'll see that they did that with Flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most browsers have this locked down for security purposes. Buttons and text boxes can be manipulated via JavaScript. File input boxes cannot, and for good reason; imagine if a javascript could open a dialog, set the path to a sensitive file on your system, then simulate the button click to download the file!

---

By the way, if you are looking to style it, perhaps this would work: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Doesn't gmail do something similar, but instead of using buttons and text input types, they seem to be using a link and possibly a span or div tag to show the files selected.  Where the link shows the upload dialog box?

Comment: I believe GMail uses Flash for their "Attach" feature. If you disable the Flash plugin, it adds good ole' fashioned file inputs.

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="inputfile"/>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('inputfile').click(); ">try this</a>
```

Try this one. I think it is useful.. :)

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, a single line is fine, but it is needed. I've arrived here from a moderation queue because this was automatically flagged. Keeping answers to high quality will help prevent that.

Comment: simple and brilliant!

Comment: Thanks @Sllouyssgort

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4BS7/1/

**NOTE:**

a) This may not work well on older browsers (mainly IE) that don't fire the change event on the file input.

b) For the upload to work as expected, you'll need to include the `<input type="file">` element in your form. The text element can be used for displaying the selected file at best.

Comment: how to add uploaded file value to another file value?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to alter an `input[type=file]` as you like, it is a purely native form element.

Besides you won't be able to get the path to the file for security reasons. Old IE versions shows the path but it is not the case anymore with newer versions and you won't be able to do anything with the path on server-side anyway.

There are though some methods to style:

- [Styling File Upload / Select Input Control](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html)
- [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)
- [Styling file inputs with CSS and the DOM](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php), I've used it many times to handle file uploading.